# How to scan barcode which will be in code 39 barcode format

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am trying to scan bar-code using zxing library, It's working good but my bar-code scan Format: CODE_128, Instead I want to CODE_39, my code is look like as below.

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this); 
scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES.);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            Log.d("scanningResult:::::", scanningResult + "");
            LOGD("scanningResult scanContent:::::", scanningResult.getContents() + "");
            LOGD("scanningResult scanFormat:::::", scanningResult.getFormatName() + "");
        }
    }
```

and I'm using these libraries in gradle

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
```

Please guys, Help to solve this problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Add following line after**     *if (scanningResult != null) {*

```
 if(scanningResult.getFormatName().compareTo(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39.toString())== 0)
 {
 //method you want to invoke when the barcode is of type code39
 }
```

And there is dot after ONE_D_CODE_TYPES , remove it .